# Run Long time executing php script even browser close

Tags: php, linux, cron, background-process

i am working on  web Payroll project using symfony framework. we have 27000 employees to process every month. when we doing employee payroll process we can not depend on browser request as it is a long time taking process and  server time out coming. as a work around we like to execute the php script from the background on linux server. then even browser closed  the scripts can excute the background.

what is the best way to do this task please help

**More info**

we would like to give the pay roll process start button from the web interface when user click on the button pay roll process should start even browser close it should execute until done from the background.

regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [php execute a background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Comment: its giving most answers to windows. we are working on LAMP stack

Comment: huh? There is no Windows answer there. They're all for Unix/Linux

Comment: ok thanks for your contribution

Comment: You are aware that the "L" in LAMP stands for Linux? The first answer in the duplicate should work well for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run in the backgroud do the following steps:

1. Wrap your php command in a shell script:

**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# set up environment variables, PATH etc. here
php  /home/yourapp/yourscript.php
```

**

1. Code up a web page/php script to request the start.
2. In the script you need the line:

   system('/home/yourapp/yourscript.sh > scriptlog.txt &'
3. You probably need an extra link to browse the "scriptlog.txt" file from the web.

Comment: Thansk james we are planing to write the out put to the database not to the text file thanks for answer good idea +1

Comment: @Roshan -- good luck. Sorry the formatting is such a mess but I can't seem to pretty it up!

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to handle this problem.

The first way is to execute , startinan shell command in background (and with using `nohup` if you like) starting from your PHP code. Thats nearly the same think like the first answer in the duplicate question.

The 2nd way is to use PHP [PCNTL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) Feature.
Using PCNTL you can create child processes, which running in background. So it's possible to make an [fork](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) and returning to the user: "pay roll process is running - you will get an mail, if the system is ready".